# How to get the Unique Identifer for Beacon in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

I have developing the application with beacons (estimote) that can receive bluetooth signal and display advertise from that udid in my iphone but how to get the udid. Is there in the hardware or i have to fetch that from the coading. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is Wojtek Borowicz, I'm a community evangelist at Estimote.

You can check Beacon's UUID, Major and Minor values using the Vritual Beacon app (https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=686915066&mt=8). It's also possible through Estimote SDK (https://github.com/Estimote) and 3rd party apps like BLExplr (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/blexplr/id524018027?mt=8).

Cheers.